# Erlang why process can't quit after using proc_lib:hibernate

Tags: erlang

I just begin studying Erlang and try to write a comet application.

Here's the thing.

For making memory usage lower, I use `proc_lib:hibernate` on feed function. But when the sockets are broken, the corresponding processes are still there, not exit.

The Code like below:

```
feed({Response, Interval, Socket}) ->            
    ok = mochiweb_socket:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),                
receive                                                              
        {Protocal, _, Bin} ->                                                     
            ok;                                                                
  {tcp_closed, _} ->                                                   
          exit(normal);                                                        
    {ssl_closed, _} ->                                                     
          exit(normal);                                                        
  {router_msg, MsgBody} ->                                                    
      RespMsg=Response:write_chunk(MsgBody);                                                                                 
    Other ->                                                                         
      exit(normal)                                                     
after Interval ->                                                              
        Response:write_chunk("HB")                                   
  end,                                                                        
proc_lib:hibernate(?MODULE, feed, [{Response, Interval, Socket}]).
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set socket options to `{active, once}` *again* before hibernating.  Otherwise, the socket will never send a message to the process, and the process therefore won't wake up from hibernation.